# SFTP using Expect

Tags: linux, shell, sftp, expect

I have tried the script below to SFTP using bash script. But it does not work. Always error at password.

```
/usr/local/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn sftp PG1@dev1.dummy.com
expect "Password:"
send "abc123\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /tmp\r"
send "get Data.dat\r"
send "get List.dat\r"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```

Here's the log file when I run the script above, after taking in all the suggestions from responders.

```
######### StartJob #########
Sun Apr 19 09:59:08 MYT 2015
spawn sftp PG1@dev1.dummy.com^M
Connecting to dev1.dummy.com...^M
Password: ^M
sftp> ERROR: Data file Data.dat not successfully extracted!
Sun Apr 19 09:59:12 MYT 2015
########## EndJob #########
```

Comment: I'm assuming there shouldn't be a space between `abc123` and `\r`

Comment: I also tried that, same error still.

Comment: After removing the space, the error seems to have changed - sftp> ERROR: Data file data.dat not successfully extracted! It is now error at sftp> instead of password.

Comment: I'd remove the space from all the commands.  You don't need it.  Then update the question with the full new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your attempts to solve the problem above. I found the solution. Here's what I did:

```
/usr/local/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn sftp PG1@dev1.dummy.com
expect "Password:"
send "abc123\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /tmp\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get Data.dat\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get List.dat\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are expecting password worth lower case p,but the log shows a capital P

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried that and same error.